# jaxb problem, error message when compiling

Tags: java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

When I compile my code I have an error because of jaxb2.
the error message:

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.4:xjc (xjc) on project commandecartes: can't parse argument number: ''http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb'': For input string: "''http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb''" -> [Help 1]

here is my pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- XML -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>

    </dependency>
    <!--generate java classes for the given xml representation-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- management of persistence and object/relational mapping in Java-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- enables distributed transactions-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PDF-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- The package of your fr.geomod.components.cmdecarte.basket.model.generated sources -->
                <packageName>fr.geomod.components.cmdecarte.basket.model.generated</packageName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried to go beyond javax, put the language in in the pom. I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You try to mix SpringBoot 3 (which is jakarta based) with javax based artifacts.

You also mixed jaxb-api 2.3 (which is javaee 8) with jaxb-runtime 4 (which is jakartaee 10) and xjc 3 (which is jakartaee 9).

My guess is the jaxb plugin is getting xjc 3 from your dependencies (which shouldnt be there) and then wants xsd / bindings in jakarta mode.

If you really target SB3, you should upgrade the plugin version with jakarta support (https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v3.1.0/index.html) and update XSD from java's jaxb namespace to jakarta's jaxb namespace `xmlns:jaxb = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"`